How to keep files downloaded with qBittorrent defragmented on BtrFS?
Files downloaded over the BitTorrent protocol are naturally fragmented as they're downloaded from pieces in irregular order.
This reduces performance when reading such files on classical HDDs. How to prevent that?

One option seems to be to check the option in qBittorrent to force pre-allocation of disk space for all files. But that wastes a lot disk space in advance, in particular if only subset of files is to be downloaded.
A better solution applicable to BtrFS is to be to configure qBittorrent (or any other similar client) to run this command on download completion:
/usr/bin/btrfs filesystem defragment -r "%F"

This ensures that files are defragmented as soon as they're downloaded.
See also:

https://btrfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Defragmentation.html
man btrfs-filesystem


Or copy to a new location and delete original. Note that in forcing sequential download it might be far slower, waiting on segments to become available.

You may set a torrent to download in sequential order by:

Right-click the torrent and select "Torrent Options"
At the bottom, check "Download in sequential order"
Click OK.

Note the announcement of
All right-click options moved into "Torrent Options" need to be restored to the right-click menu #16273
means that at some time in the near future, this option will change its
position in the context menu.

Note that sequential downloads pretty much go against the design of the BitTorrent protocol. See vuze.com: Sequential downloading is bad.
